# Find out the five product groups with the highest average standard cost in 2012 (the StartDate is in 2012)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, average

This is what I came up with but can't wrap my head around it. It's my sub-query that's getting the error. Please help!

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(P.Name, 1, CHARINDEX('1',P.Name)) AS ProductGroups
FROM Product P
JOIN ProductCostHistory PCH ON ( PCH.ProductID = P.ProductID )
WHERE (
    SELECT TOP (5) AVG(PCH.StandardCost) 
    FROM ProductCostHistory PCH 
    WHERE StartDate = 2012
);
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Your `WHERE` clause isn't doing anything because it doesn't have a predicate it just has a table expression. There should be some kind of expression there that evaluates to true or false. Also, your subquery is only ever going to return one row because it isn't grouped on anything so the TOP 5 isn't doing anything either.

Comment: Mike , how do I find the average of the top 5 groups with the highest standard cost. That's where it's really confusing me. Sorry I'm new to sql so i'm learning very slowly...

Comment: What type is your StartDate column?

Comment: Is it sql 2008 or 2012

Comment: @rdubya - its datetime.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% clear but the below should get you close.

The subquery pulls the `TOP 5` average costs by `ProductID`, this is then `JOIN`ed to your `Product` table. Your subquery was missing a `GROUP BY` so it would have been the average across all products, not the average by product, it was also missing an `ORDER BY` so it would have given the first 5 products it calculated, not the 5 highest.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(P.Name, 1, CHARINDEX('1',P.Name)) AS ProductGroups, q.ProductID,.q.AvgCost
FROM Product P
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT TOP (5) PCH.ProductID, AVG(PCH.StandardCost) As AvgCost
    FROM ProductCostHistory PCH 
    WHERE PCH.StartDate = 2012
    GROUP BY PCH.ProductID
    ORDER BY AVG(PCH.StandardCost) Desc
) As q ON (p.ProductID = q.ProductID)
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Simon. I think I have an idea of how to go about this. I'll post the answer once I figure it out! Thanks a bunch for the help!

Answer (score 0):

As you are using SQL Server 2012, you can use the `row_number` analytic function with order by on average standard cost and return top 5 products

```
 With CTE as
 (
      SELECT  productid    ,
      Avg(standardcost) as avgCost,
      Row_number() over ( partition by productid order by avg(standard cost) desc) as rn
     FROM ProductCostHistory         WHERE StartDate = 2012
     Group by productid
   )
   SELECT SUBSTRING(P.Name, 1, CHARINDEX('1',P.Name)) AS      ProductGroups,
  CTE.avgCost
  FROM Product P
 JOIN Cte 
 On CTE.productid = p.productid
 And CTE.rn <= 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys so after modifying what Simon posted, I ended up with the results! Just wanted to say thanks to everyone that helped out!

```
SELECT TOP 5 (substring(P.Name, 1, CHARINDEX(' ',P.Name))) AS ProductGroups,AVG(PCH.StandardCost) AS AverageStandardCost,P.ProductID AS ProductID 
FROM Product P 
INNER JOIN ProductCostHistory PCH ON (PCH.ProductID = P.ProductID) 
WHERE PCH.StartDate 
LIKE '%2012%' 
GROUP BY P.Name, P.ProductID
ORDER BY AVG(PCH.StandardCost) DESC
```

Let me know if you agree ?